# What happens when std::iterator is accessed outside its boundary(end)?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I tried to run below code to check the accessibility of iterator :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> n = {1,24,5,4};
    vector<int> :: iterator itr;

    itr = n.begin();
    for(;;itr++){
        cout<<*itr<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program executed and exited with segmentation fault at the end.
What i understood from it that upto certain iterations the value returned by iterator is zero outside its boundary and after that program crashes.
I want to know what happens when we access the iterator outside its boundary and if it acts like a pointer , what does it point to?

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: _"I want to know what happens when we access the iterator outside its boundary ..."_ You might have killed a cradle of cute kittens. It's not possible to tell what happens with calling _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Although, in all fairness, the cute kittens were probably possessed by nasal demons, so good riddance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Anything* can happen. It is Undefined Behaviour and the compiler is not required to do anything specific. In fact, it is allowed to treat your *entire* program as invalid and emit *whatever code it wants* if your program contains UB *anywhere*.

Once you break the rules of the language (like dereferencing an iterator pointing to something that is out-of-bounds), you leave the realm of well defined C++ and you can no longer have *any* expectations as to what the behaviour will be.

Comment: Well thanks for answer, yes understood its an undefined behavior when accessed the iterator 
 outside scope. The code won't crash when i'm accessing upto a small number of iterations(say 10), might be accessing the values from arbitrary locations.

Comment: @VikasRokade "The code won't crash when i'm accessing upto a small number of iterations(say 10)" - There is *NO guarantee* of that. It's still UB and with a different compiler, different optimization options, a different hardware platform or just a slightly different run-time environment it may well crash (or worse; seem to work, corrupt memory silently and crash 10hrs later in the middle of the night at your biggest customer).